# C++ "argument list for class template "iterator" is missing" error

Tags: c++, class, templates

I've got this class:

```
template<typename T>
class Konten
{
    enum { ssize = 100 };
    T stack[ssize];
    int top;
public:
    Konten() : top(0) {}
    void push(T i) {
        assert(top < ssize);  stack[top++] = i;
    };
    T pop() {
        assert(top > 0);  return stack[--top];
    };
    int rozmiar() { return top; };

    class iterator {
        Konten& s;
        int index;
    public:
        iterator(Konten& is) : s(is), index(0) {};
        iterator(Konten& is, bool) : s(is), index(s.top) {};
        T operator++() { // Prefix
            assert(index < s.top);
            return s.stack[++index];
        };
        T operator++(int) { // Postfix
            assert(index < s.top);
            return s.stack[index++];
        };
        T& operator*() const { return s.stack[index]; };
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& rv) {
            s = rv.s;
            index = rv.index;
            return *this;
        }
    };
    iterator begin() { return iterator(*this); };
    iterator end() { return iterator(*this, true); };

    friend class iterator;
};
```

And as you see it has another class inside it. I want to create an object of the iterator class this way:

```
Konten<double> pier;
iterator it1(pier);
```

But I keep on getting following error: "argument list for class template "iterator" is missing".

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterator needs to be declared as `Konten<double>::iterator`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's my first time doing such, so I was confused as hell!

Comment: The actual error suggests @Ania has included `<iterator>` and then done `using namespace std;`.